# apendding child inside an <li> not working

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I just had my first DOM class and my teacher gave me a test that's blowing my mind (althought it is pbp simple to you guys. I need to display some elements on my window using js. Everything's was going ok until i had to append a tag inside another tag. The tags im supossed to use are

, , ,

Basically i need to store everything inside the

and thats the part i'm having a hard time on

```
let itens = [
    {
        Imagem: "./assets/img/painting/gamepad.jpg",
        Nome: "Gamepad",
        Preco: "$50.00",
        Classe: "Painting",

    },

    {
        Imagem: "./assets/img/painting/clock.jpg",
        Nome: "Clock",
        Preco: "$89.99",
        Classe: "Painting",


    },

    {
        Imagem: "./assets/img/painting/personagem.jpg",
        Nome: "R2D2",
        Preco: "$1999.99",
        Classe: "Painting",


    },

    {
        Imagem: "./assets/img/actions/animewoman.jpg",
        Nome: "Anime WOman",
        Preco: "$299.99",
        Classe: "Action Figure",


    },

    {
        Imagem: "./assets/img/actions/dragonballpersonagem.jpg",
        Nome: "Goku",
        Preco: "$10.99",
        Classe: "Action Figure",


    },

    {
        Imagem: "./assets/img/actions/starwarspersonagem.jpg",
        Nome: "Baby Yoda",
        Preco: "$30.99",
        Classe: "Action Figure",


    },

]

let lists = []
let images = []
let titles = []
let prices = []

for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    lists[i] = document.createElement('li')
    titles[i] = document.createElement('h1')
    images[i] = document.createElement('img')
    prices[i] = document.createElement('p')
}

//Definindo valores das tags


for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    if (itens[i].Classe == "Painting") {
        lists[i].className = "paintingObj"

    } else {
        lists[i].className = "actionObj"
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = itens[i].Imagem
    images[i].width = 207
    images[i].height = 275

}

for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    titles[i].innerHTML = itens[i].Nome

}

for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    prices[i].innerHTML = itens[i].Preco

}
```

Everytime i try lets say:

```
lists[0].appendChild(images[0])
```

... OR MAYBE...

```
lists[0].appendChild(prices[3]
```

IT SIMPLE DOES NOT ADD THE VALUE INSIDE THE ARRAY IVE CHOSEN

Oh btw, i KNOW there're a lot of other ways i could accomplish the task he gave me, but i'm just trying to solve it with the knowledge i already got

I tried using commas
i tried converting to string... to undefined and neither of these worked

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use this sample from MDN to append an element:

```
let ul = document.createElement("div")
let p = document.createElement("p") div.append("Some text", p)
```

To add data from your JSON use:

```
items.forEach(item) { <p>item.images</p> }
```